# PHP - Juntando dados de 2 Tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoa, sou novo no Fórum gostaria de pedi a primeira ajuda. Resumindo bastante: Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de chamados, onde ele junta dados de outros sistemas.

Eu gostaria de exibir todos os dados de 2 tabelas sql em uma tebela php, cada linha existe informações de uma tabela.

- tabela 1
- tabela 2
- tabela 1
- tabela 2

Só encontrei informações sobre join, mas esse não me ajudaria pois junta os dados na mesma coluna, e eu gostaria de linhas separadas pra cada tabela do banco de dados.

estou fazendo assim:

```
<?php       
$servidor = "localhost"; /*maquina a qual o banco de dados está*/
$banco = "xxxx"; /*seleciona o banco a ser usado*/
$usuario = "root"; /*usuario do banco de dados MySql*/
$senha = ""; /*senha do banco de dados MySql*/

$conexao = mysql_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);
/*Conecta no bando de dados MySql*/
mysql_select_db($banco);
/*seleciona o banco a ser usado*/
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM base_itg, base_spn");
/*Executa o comando SQL, no caso para pegar todos os chamados  e retorna o valor da consulta em uma variavel ($res)  */
?>
```

e depois posto na tela

```
                while($escrever=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                    $id = $escrever['id'];  /*Escreve cada linha da tabela*/
                    echo "<tr>  
                            <td> <a href = 'detalhe.php?id=$id' target =_blank>" . $escrever["bl_situacao"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bi_sistema"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bl_local_atendimento"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bl_uf"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bl_chamado"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bl_criado_em"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bl_resumo"] . "</td>
                        </tr>";
                     echo "<tr> 
                            <td> <a href = 'pages/detalhados/spn.php?id=$id' target =_blank>" . $escrever["bs_status"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bs_sistema"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bs_sistema"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bs_sistema"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bs_sistema"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bs_sistema"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $escrever["bs_sistema"] . "</td>

                        </tr>";
                }/*Fim do while*/
```

eu consigo mostrar os dados simultaneamente, porém com um erro, ele ficam duplicados.

Se somando os dados das duas tabelas eu tenho 4 items, ele mostra 8.

Comment: mas o que não entendi é a razão de eu dizer pc.marca = c.marca, pois são duas coisas distintas.

Comment: eu quero pegar todas as linhas de 2 tabelas, e mostrar 1 linha embaixo da outra.

Comment: eu gostaria de linhas diferentes, uma com celular e outra com computador.

Comment: melhor editar a pergunta e explicar o seguinte: 1 - estrutura das tabelas, 2 - campos a serem selecionados na consulta, 3 - filtro que deseja usar para seleção

Comment: reformulei minha pergunta, e postei o código para um melhor entendimento.

Comment: Ainda não vou dar uma resposta porque não entendi uma coisa, seu segundo echo vai mostrar 6 colunas com a mesma informação ? `<td>" . $escrever["bs_sistema"] . "</td>` é isso mesmo ?

Comment: Vala uma leitura: Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/13561

Comment: em vez de join, use Union, faça duas consultas independentes e use o union para juntá-las.

Comment: isso por enquanto é um teste, ele atualmente ta mostrando a mesma informação. Agradeço a atenção e peço desculpa pela formulação do meu questionário, mas consegui resolver o meu problema colocando um loop dentro de um loop;

Comment: não poderia usar UNION?